# jqGrid - displaying a PDF in a new window when the link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf, jqgrid

I am creating a web application in Visual Studio Express 2012 which loads data from an XML file included with the web application and displays it in a grid.  Using jQuery 1.9.1, jqGrid 4.5.2, jquery-ui-1.10.4.  The grid is populated when a button is clicked.  The XML file structure is as follows:

```
<Recordset setCount="1">
<Record setEntry="0">
<PROD_NAME>Broth</PROD_NAME>
<MFR>Swanson</MFR>
<DATE_MODIFIED>September 24, 2012 10:05:35</DATE_MODIFIED>
<IMAGE>PDFTest\test1.pdf</IMAGE>
</Record>
</Recordset>
```

The **IMAGE** tag contains a link to a folder located below the `default.aspx` page & the XML file.

I have a custom formatter for that column, which returns a link.  However, the link cannot be opened.  The formattter is:

```
 {name: "IMAGE", xmlmap: "Recordset>Record>IMAGE",
  formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
  return '<a href="file:///' + cellValue + '" target="_blank" >' + cellValue + '</a>';
       }
  },
```

I've verified that the path & the file to the image is valid and the image exists.  How do you make a jqGrid hyperlink open a PDF file that is local to the web application?

Answer (score 0):

make sure local resourse exist because this will try to load local resource as you are using file:///.

please open same link in new browser window to cross check whether it is opening in browser.